# Write comment in matlab plot using script

Tags: matlab, plot

I need to plot a few points in a graph and then write a comment next to each point. How can I do this?

I plotted the points like this

```
plot(5000,  211   , 'o')
hold on;
plot(5000,  100    , 'o')
plot(5000,  20     , 'o')
```

and then i need to write a comment next to each "o".
I tried using the same method but it didn't work.

```
plot(5000,  215   , 'some comment')
```

How to solve this most easily?

Comment: Use [**`text`**](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/text.html) like this - `text(5000,215,'some comment')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like that for that particular point (adapt spaces for your use)

```
text(5000, 211, '   some comment', 'FontSize',12)
```

To add arrows, use something like:

```
text(5000, 211, ' \leftarrow some comment', 'FontSize',12)
```

Also check the [Matlab docs](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-to-graphs.html) on annotating graphs.

Comment: You're welcome. Just for the sake of completeness, if your question was answered, mark it as answered, so that it does not show up as unanswered in the list.